# google map direction with multiple colors

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-directions-api, stroke, polylineoptions

I trace route between two points using directions API google map .I want to use one color for the  route starting from pickup point to the middle point route , and the other half of route another color.

Example :

The route contains two colors

From A to middle route : color and from middle to end point B another color

Comment: You need to provide what you've worked on, with ideally a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). People here have no idea how you are implementing stuff, what libraries, how you are drawing this, etc.

Comment: This looks like an exact duplicate of a question asked and closed yesterday.  If the duplicates aren't helpful, please see [ask].